# memcache set explictly exception

Tags: google-app-engine

in our gwt +GAE for java app I see following exception without any clue why it's happening. any one?

/adminmodule/admin
com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$CancelledException: The API call memcache.Set() was explicitly cancelled.
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl$5.get(ApiProxyImpl.java:367)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl$5.get(ApiProxyImpl.java:364)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.appstats.RecordingFuture.get(RecordingFuture.java:108)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.appstats.Recorder.processRecordingFuture(Recorder.java:431)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.appstats.Recorder.processAsyncRpc(Recorder.java:404)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.appstats.RecordingFuture.maybeRecordStats(RecordingFuture.java:140)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.appstats.RecordingFuture.get(RecordingFuture.java:110)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.appstats.RecordingFuture.get(RecordingFuture.java:20)
    at com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:86)
    at com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:86)
    at com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServiceImpl.quietGet(MemcacheServiceImpl.java:26)
    at com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServiceImpl.putAll(MemcacheServiceImpl.java:110)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.appstats.MemcacheWriter.persist(MemcacheWriter.java:268)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.appstats.MemcacheWriter.commit(MemcacheWriter.java:189)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.appstats.AppstatsFilter.doFilter(AppstatsFilter.java:151)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:102)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:35)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:266)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:146)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:447)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:454)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:461)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:703)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:338)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:330)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:458)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this was due to incorrect pm state. the pm state was sometimes closed even before other operations were completed.

this was resolved by initiating the pm object locally.

Comment: What is pm state? What does pm mean?